# SQLite database backup

Tags: python, database, sqlite

For backup of SQLite database, I went through https://www.sqlite.org/backup.html 
I came to know that there is one python wrapper over these SQLite online backup APIs.So, I went through https://github.com/husio/python-sqlite3-backup
Here are some doubts that I have about sqlitebck(python package)

1. I checked out the code in tests, it shows db is copied from :memory: to file and vice versa using sqlitebck.copy(:memory:,dbfile), I am confused about ":memory:" and its use.
2. Instead from memory, can I copy one database file to other database file like sqlitebck(dbfile1, dbfile2). so that dbfile2 will be the backup of dbfile1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`':memory:'` as a "filename" is how you tell sqlite to keep a small DB in memory rather than on-disk.  But yes, `sqlitebck` is fine to copy from file to file -- though the arguments it takes are sqlite **connections** so you'd need to `sqlite3.connect` to each file first (and usually might as well just copy the file directly w/o involving `sqlite` -- as the sqlite page you link to implies, suggesting Unix `cp` or Windows `copy`... Python has its own standard library module for file copies, https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html ).

Comment: Do not copy the db file while it is open because it can create a [corrupted](https://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html) database copy. Use the SQLite backup API.